Should I use a GFCI breaker in the load center for a 50 Amp generator circuit?
Should a 50 amp exterior receptacle be wired to a load center gfci breaker or can a regular 50 amp breaker be used? Generator bonded neutral has been modified to floating neutral and is intended to be used as a temporary power source directly connected to load center only.

I assume you meant a 50 amp inlet and not a regular receptacle and a suicide cord.  I think you use a regular breaker, since you would be powering any/all GFCIs breakers/receptacles.  You also need an interlock for the 50 amp breaker and main breaker.

First -- you need to use a "generator interlock" in the panel, which is a sliding-plate affair that forces the main breaker to be off before the generator breaker can be turned on.
Second, the so-called "receptacle" on your house that the generator plugs into must be an inlet.
The entire concept of North American electrical is the thing that TAKES power has metal prongs, since it is dead when not plugged in... and the thing which GIVES power has slots to protect fingers from being shocked.   Since the house takes power, that must be an inlet.   "But isn't the inlet energized when the utility power is on?" No, the interlock makes that impossible.
Now, with that resolved, you must use a plain breaker because you are back-feeding the panel. That is, running power "backwards" through the breaker.  Plain breakers handle that just fine - but GFCI/AFCI breakers cannot handle this!
By the way, backfeeding is fine and legal - many OEM panels do this for the main breaker.  However, a back-fed breaker must have a tie-down kit installed. If you look close at the link, you see a silver dot on the main breaker, that's a tie-down screw.

You MUST use a regular 50A breaker for the generator side of your interlock.  (The GFCI will fry if you try using it instead.)
Electronic circuit breakers, such as ground fault circuit interruptors, cannot tolerate being backfed, as would be required to use one for a generator feed.  (The reverse power connection can cause serious damage to internal electronics due to the power to the circuitry not being shutoff when the breaker trips.  Fried trip solenoids or solenoid trigger SCRs are the usual failure mode here.)
As a result, you must use a regular old two-pole, 50A breaker of the correct type for your panel along with the appropriate interlock kit, a 50A inlet box, and a generator cord (which has only one male end on it!!!!!) to hook up your generator.
